# Can't replay minimal script, compilation error

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I'm starting a new project on a new computer with Windows 10 and a new installation of LoadRunner Community Edition 12.60.

I created the absolutely most minimal VuGen script possible and called it `dont-suck`. Shift-F5 claims to compile just fine. Replay (F5) yields these errors though:

```
Error: CCI compilation error -error: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\LoadRunner\bin\cpp.exe: c:\users\mark\documents\vugen\scripts\dont-suck\\pre_cci.c: Permission denied.
Error: Vuser compilation failed.
Warning: Extension cciext.dll reports error -19800 on call to function ExtPerProcessInitialize
Error: Thread Context: Call to service of the driver failed, reason - thread context wasn't initialized on this thread.
```

I've gone through the reinstall and reboot routine a few times. That `pre_cci.c` file is generated in the build process and I have all rights to it, so "permission denied" makes no sense.

I don't get why this extremely simple script is so hard to run. What is going on that is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

*Found it.* The new computer came with the McAfee LiveSafe real-time security scanner enabled. Disabling the real-time scanner solved the problem.

Comment: If you work with LoadRunner in your day to day, we would love to get some feedback from you.

Comment: I'm really new with LoadRunner, but sure, let's talk. See your Twitter.